# woocommerce admin product search multiple skus

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, code-snippets

So, I work for a sales business that has just setup a webstore using Wordpress with the Woocommerce plugin.

What I want to be able to do deals with the admin search on the products tab where all the information for our products is held.
From what I understand, the normal search does a mySQL query for the terms you put in the box.  I have a code snippet in functions.php to allow it to search the meta field _sku as well.  So when i enter a sku number of say... 7026
it will pull up any items with 7026 in its title, description or sku.

However, I want to be able to enter say.... 7026  4567  3883
into the search box and it query the database to find any product that matches any of those numbers (an OR relational search instead of AND)
right now if i type that in i get nothing because it searches for any product that has 7026 AND 4567 AND 3883 in the title, decription, or sku, but what my goal is to have the search return at the least the 3 products in our database that have the skus 7026, 4567, and 3883

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have tried to get a code snippet working for days with no luck.

Comment: You should add the code that you have tried **in your question,** even if it doesn't work for instance.

Comment: i'll see if i can get that posted, excellent point

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this post:
[mutli sku admin search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707710/search-multiple-skus-on-woocommerce-admin-side)

The code in the post is from Bjorn, thank you so much.

the code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Use multiple sku's to find WOO products in wp-admin
 * NOTE: Use '|' as a sku delimiter in your search query. Example: '1234|1235|1236'
**/
function woo_multiple_sku_search( $query_vars ) {

global $typenow;
global $wpdb;
global $pagenow;

if ( 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
    $search_term = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );

    if (strpos($search_term, '|') == false) return $query_vars;

    $skus = explode('|',$search_term);

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
    );
    if(is_array($skus) && $skus) {
        foreach($skus as $sku) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $sku,
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }
    }

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'meta_query'      => $meta_query
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    if ( ! $posts ) return $query_vars;

    foreach($posts as $post){
      $query_vars['post__in'][] = $post->ID;
    }
}

return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'woo_multiple_sku_search', 20 );
```