# WooCommerce search for multiple orders

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, code-snippets

With inspiration in this post - [woocommerce admin product search multiple skus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437051/woocommerce-admin-product-search-multiple-skus/61770224)
I am trying add a search for multiple orders to WooCommerce
Is it possible to tweak this code to make it work for orders instead of products?

```
function woo_multiple_order_search( $query_vars ) {

global $typenow;
global $wpdb;
global $pagenow;

if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
    $search_term = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );

    if (strpos($search_term, '|') == false) return $query_vars;

    $order_ids = explode('|',$search_term);

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
    );

    if(is_array($order_ids) && $order_ids) {
        foreach($order_ids as $order_id) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => '_order_id',
                'value' => $order_id,
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }
    }

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'meta_query'      => $meta_query
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args ); 

    if ( ! $posts ) return $query_vars;

    foreach($posts as $post){
      $query_vars['post__in'][] = $post->ID;
    }
}

return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'woo_multiple_order_search', 20 );
```

Seems to be working until foreach($posts as $post){

Comment: What have you tried so far? the code you placed here is exactly the same as the url you shared

Comment: code changed to what Im using.

Comment: Anyone? a bit stuck on this one, I am thinking it should be some small tweaking, just can't figure out what to tweak to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfect if you change '_order_id' by the correct field name '_order_number' in this part:

```
        foreach($order_ids as $order_id) {
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => '_order_number', // correct field name
                'value' => $order_id,
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }
```